# Htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I am trying to redirect from
http://www.domain.com/prod.php?id=23  To http://www.domain.com/index.php?q=35

I tried something like the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/prod.php\?products_id=23$ $1/index.php?q=35 [NC,L]
```

But not working

The following works but I want the redirection for specific query string.

```
redirect /prod.php http://www.domain.com/index.php?q=35 [NC,L]
```

I got it, it was

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^products_id=23 [NC]
RewriteRule prod\.php$ /index.php?q=35 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you absolutely need the url to look like: /prod.php?id=32 or you can go to a more SEO oriented URL like: /product/32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm dealing with mod_rewrite to redirect my urls and to train myself I
>   was looking Stack overflow posts with the tag `redirect`... not important
>
> I stumbled upon this resolved post but turns out like it has
>   no accepted answer (just an edit in the question) but the post then
>   remains in the unanswered posts stack, consider the following answer
>   as the accepted one, or write it yourself and check it as well for the
>   benefit of the community...

**acceptable answer**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=23 [NC]
RewriteRule ^prod\.php$ /index.php?q=35 [R,QSA,L]
```